# Angular webpage not showing meta tags in FB

Tags: angularjs, facebook, debugging, seo

My webpage is odalternatives.com/5-questions-that-can-transform-leaders-and-their-organizations

With reference to this Page - https://rck.ms/angular-handlebars-open-graph-facebook-share/

i try to fix but failed

.httpaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://www.odalternatives.com/static.php?id=$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

static.php which need to be rendered by FB TWITTER is

```
<?php
// 1. get the content Id (here: an Integer) and sanitize it properly
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// 2. get the content from a flat file (or API, or Database, or ...)
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('./meta/'.$id.'.json'));

// 3. return the page
return makePage($data); 

function makePage($data) {
    // 1. get the page
    $pageUrl = $data->id;
    // 2. generate the HTML with open graph tags
    $html  = '<!doctype html>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta name="author" content="'.$data->name.'"/>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$data->title.'"/>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta property="og:description" content="'.$data->description.'"/>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$data->poster.'"/>'.PHP_EOL;
    // 3. return the page
    echo $html;
}
```

BUt when i paste link in FB or anywhere else it shows me this

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fodalternatives.com%2F5-questions-that-can-transform-leaders-and-their-organizations

Comment: _“HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.”_ – that is an issue with your server. So go check what the request that comes in looks like (server logs, perhaps some additional logging in your script), and go check the server configuration for what limits might be set in that regard.

Comment: Thanx for your comment... from where did you come to know about this error.....

Comment: From the debug tool output. If I reload the link you posted above several times, it sometimes shows what looks like the full page source code, and sometimes just the code of this error document.

Comment: Debug tool page i showing BAD REQUEST.... how can i fix this any idea...

Comment: Again: That is an error issued by _your_ server (/your script), so you will need to do some debugging on your end.